# Exclude some data from a vector

Tags: matlab

Let's suppose I have a vector that contain numbers between `1..100`, and then I generate some number randomly (let's suppose five item and random Items are `[3 5 45 66 77]`. Then I want to exclude this item from my data.

```
data = [1..100]
blocklistitems=[3 5 45 66 77]
cleandata = data exclude blocklist
```

**How can I exclude some data from a vector in Matlab?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = [1..100]
blocklistitems=[3 5 45 66 77]
data(blocklistitems)=[]; %// completely removes, reduces length of array
data(blocklistitems)=nan; %// sets to nan
```

Utilising indexing!

Judging your comment I think your data is not as simple as you present in your answer, since in that case the indexing way is the fastest by far. Taking [@Divakar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696966/exclude-some-data-from-a-vector/33697010?noredirect=1#comment55188026_33697010) using [`setdiff`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) the same can be accomplished for non-consecutive integer arrays:

```
C = setdiff(data,blocklistitems);
```

Comment: after some research I found using `setdiff` is better solution , please provide it too in your answer till I make it as acceptable answer.

Comment: @Adriaan Just add `setdiff` into it as another approach! :)